# Auth headers not working ajax 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'myurl.com',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password')
  },
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

[image]

Any ideas why the server is responding with 401 Unauthorized? Username and password are correct and the request works fine outside of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You see response to so called pre-flight OPTIONS request, not the GET request. Your server should handle it properly.

For more information please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests